# Datagridview row color base on cell value(group no)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datarow

```
Dim db As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    db.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(System.String))
    db.Columns.Add("Grp", GetType(System.Int32))

    db.Rows.Add("Peter", "1")
    db.Rows.Add("Jack", "1")
    db.Rows.Add("Smith", "2")
    db.Rows.Add("Mechael", "2")
    db.Rows.Add("John", "3")
    db.Rows.Add("John", "3")
    db.Rows.Add("John", "3")
    db.Rows.Add("Kelly John", "4")
    db.Rows.Add("Kelly John", "4")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = db

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Grp").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan
    End If
End Sub
```

I have use the DataGridView1_RowPrePaint event to change the row color base on the group no and it works correctly but when I sort name column it color them incorrectly.

Please see visual below... Thanks in Advance for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Why it's incorrect in the second picture? You're coloring the even groups. Both pictures are correct.

Comment: Because the color should change if the group no changes... in above picture the color should be blue for group no 1 and white for group no 3 and blue for group no 4 and white for 2 and blue for 1 and white 2... Hope i am clear.

Comment: That's not gonna happend never beacuse of DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Grp").Value Mod 2 = 0... With that you're coloring the even groups. The order does not matter.